# MomentsJS asHours formatting

Tags: momentjs

I have a result in milliseconds and I am trying to display it as Hours and Minutes using Momentjs.

```
var x = 161545000;
var tempResult = moment.duration(x);

var formattedX = tempResult.asHours() + 'h ' + tempResults.minutes() + 'm ';
```

What is being displayed:

```
2.2701202777777776h 16m
```

What I want, but can't seem to format it right:

```
2h 16m
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395614/format-moment-js-duration

Answer (score 5):

How about using `Math.floor()`?

```
var formattedX = Math.floor(tempResult.asHours()) + 'h ' +
    Math.floor(tempResults.minutes()) + 'm ';
```

Or, better yet, use the `Moment#hours()` method instead of `Moment#asHours()`:

```
var formattedX = tempResult.hours() + 'h ' + tempResults.minutes() + 'm ';
```

Comment: Just a note... if your value is over 24 hours, like 25 hours and 30 minutes, your output will be 1h 30m