# Format Moment.js Duration

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to track the duration of an action in my app. Currently, I have the following code:

```
var startMoment = null;

var actionClock = null;
function startClock() {
  actionClock = setInterval(function(){ 
    if (startMoment === null) {
      startMoment = moment();
      $('#duration').text('00:00:00');
    } else {
      var now = moment();
      var span = moment.duration(now - startMoment);
      $('#duration').text(span.minutes() + ':' + span.seconds() + '.' + span.milliseconds());
    }
  }, 1000);     
}

function stopClock() {          
  clearInterval(actionClock);

      var now = moment();
      var span = moment.duration(now - startMoment);
      $('#duration').text(span.minutes() + ':' + span.seconds() + '.' + span.milliseconds());

  startMoment = null;
  actionClock = null;
}
```

My problem is, the format of duration is awkward. I want to display the duration as mm:ss.lll. In other words, always show two digits for the minutes, two digits for the seconds, and three digits for the milliseconds. Currently, I see durations printed like `1:2.45`. How do I format a duration created with Moment.js? If this is not possible, is there another library I should be using to track a duration and display it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing this might be to convert your duration back into a moment (perhaps using milliseconds), and then using the moment's formatting.

```
moment.utc(span.asMilliseconds()).format('mm:ss.SSS');
```

```js
var startMoment = null,
  $durForm = $('#durationFormatted');

var actionClock = null;

function startClock() {
  actionClock = setInterval(function() {
    if (startMoment === null) {
      startMoment = moment();
      $('#duration').text('00:00:00');
      $durForm.text('00:00.000');
    } else {
      var now = moment();
      var span = moment.duration(now - startMoment);
      $('#duration').text(span.minutes() + ':' + span.seconds() + '.' + span.milliseconds());
      $durForm.text(moment(span.asMilliseconds()).format('mm:ss.SSS'));
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stopClock() {
  clearInterval(actionClock);

  var now = moment();
  var span = moment.duration(now - startMoment);
  $('#duration').text(span.minutes() + ':' + span.seconds() + '.' + span.milliseconds());
  $durForm.text(moment(span.asMilliseconds()).format('mm:ss.SSS'));

  startMoment = null;
  actionClock = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<div>Duration (original): <span id='duration'></span>
</div>
<div>Formatted moment: <span id='durationFormatted'></span>
</div>
<button onClick='startClock()'>Start Clock</button>
<button onClick='stopClock()'>Stop Clock</button>
```

Comment: To prevent moment from adding local timezone, must be used `moment.utc()` factory method.

Comment: I would expect this to break with a greater than 23:59:59 duration.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in my project and thankfully, Lodash was already a dependency. I was able to use the _.padStart method to get there.

```
let yourHours = _.padStart(span.hours().toString(),2,'0');
let yourMinute = _.padStart(span.minutes().toString(),2,'0');
let yourSeconds = _.padStart(span.seconds().toString(),2,'0');
```